# symfony installation and $_POST all vars to an array

Tags: php, symfony, request

I want to run my $_POST, $_GET, $_SERVER and $_SESSION values with the symfony request class.

Which files are be enough to copy of https://github.com/symfony/symfony to run this class

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

Can someone tell me also, how to $_POST all vars to an array. I'm doing that now with

```
$post_data = array();

foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
{
    $post_data[$field] = $value;
}
```

Comment: All you really need is the [HTTP Foundation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) component. And $_POST is already an array.  No need to convert it to one.

Comment: Think I'll back away slowly on this one.  You don't "put a component into a file".

Comment: Take a peak inside of Request.php and if you don't immediately understand why using it in isolation simply will not work then take some time learning the basics of php and find yourself a tutorial using composer as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
mkdir request
cd request
composer require symfony/http-foundation
```

Add a file called test.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$request = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();

print_r($request);
```

And then:

```
php test.php
```

You just won't get very far with modern components without some understanding of composer, namespaces and autoloading.

This might help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have all your post datas with `$request->request`

Comment: why do you want to construct another array ? you still have an array with `$request->request`